# How to run .bat file when deploying java spring boot project on tomcat?

Tags: java, spring-boot, batch-file, tomcat9

I have batch file 'turnOff.bat' to turn off sound in system

```
cd C:\Users\xxx\nircmd\
nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 1
```

Here is the java spring code that uses that file:

```
try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "cmd /c turnOff.bat", null, new File("/test"));

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

when I run it on intellIj it works normally but when I export the war file to run on tomcat it can't work.
I have button in client, when I click on the button will call this api `/manager/sound`, Here is the error message after I click:
`GET http://localhost:4000/manager/sound 404`.

Please help me if you know anything about it!

Comment: 404, what does that tell you?

Comment: I have button in client, when I click on the button will call this api, This api don't active when I run project on tomcat

Comment: When you run your application _locally_ "localhost" will be resolved to your machine and thus the url should be mapped to your application. When the application is deployed to the _server_ what do you think "localhost" will be mapped to? (hint: it's still your local machine ...)

Comment: Btw, "GET http://localhost:4000/manager/sound 404." and "run .bat file when deploying on tomcat" are totally different things. The former is about a url/api not reachable while the latter is about running a batch file on the system your application is running on. They might be linked but are technically different. - That being said, here's another note since I have the feeling that's what you want to achieve: your application _cannot_ execute batch files on your local client machine if it is deployed on a server.

Comment: @Thomas If you say, it will still be able to run that .bat file. I am understanding is that

Comment: @Thomas I am understanding that since I cannot run this .bat file, my api has an error, it cannot return the responsive to the client so it has a 404 error.

Comment: 404 means "not found", i.e. Tomcat (assuming you're running it on your machine) can't find the url you're calling. Unless you've changed a mapping any `IOException` when trying to call the batch file should just get printed and result in a 200 while any other exception should result in a 500. So either you've changed your mapping or your code doesn't get executed because the url isn't correct or mapped correctly (hard to tell with the little info you've provided).

Comment: Can you tell me why it can't be found when I'm running on tomcat? Although on IntellIj it can still run normally. That's the problem I'm having here!